# Texture inside out (XNALara) .idk what im doing

Tags: texturing, uv

TLDR :
texture inside out of solid.
im a beginner at blender and practicing it.
so idk whats happening.
i appologize if i sound ignorant or seems to be stupid but i've done some research about this and have 0 clue on how to fix it still.

XNALara was used. (ver. 2.0.2).

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wzuh.jpg

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search Flip Normals. If that doesn't work press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> while the image texture is selected in the *Shader Editor*. Try using object/generated coordinates.

You might also want to try applying the scale and location, and apply all geometry shifting modifiers like *Solidify* or *Subdiv*.

I am not an expert, that is just the troubleshooting procedure I would have tried based on my very high number of mistakes.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IdbHPFq
thanks. i fixed it by randomly pressing everything and crashing blender over and over again untill i found this one tiny button called " Show backface"

i did what you said too and it "kinda" worked but not the solution it needed. thank you for the guide on how to fix similar solution in the future

Comment: @Chrome Hello and welcome. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing blend mode in material settings
[image: blender material settings, blend mode]